# Pass an int pointer then check for a value or null

Tags: c, pointers, null

I want to pass a ptr to a function and have the function determine if the value is a number or `NULL`. The reason for this is to avoid writing two functions one to check for commonly returned error indicators from C's built-in functions.

Currently, I'm using two duplicate functions one to check for returned `int` of `-1` and one to check for returned `char *ptr` of `NULL`. This somewhat violates DRY as the actions on both functions are the same outside of what is being tested. I've considered writing a 3rd function to handle the action, but I wanted to check with the community to see if there is a better method.

Example code of what I'm looking to accomplish:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

typedef union combo_tag {
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
} combo;

int foo(combo test) {
    if (test.fp == NULL || test.i == -1) {
        printf("error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    combo a;

    // attempt to produce an error
    a.fp = fopen("/tmp/somthing-that-does-not-exist/file", "a");
    a.i  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    return foo(a);
}
```

Comment: An int can't be null. You can declare a as an int* and set it to null.

Comment: Also, you should check for `ptr == NULL || *ptr == -1`. That way you short circuit out, before dereferencing null. And you should indicate errors by something other than printing to screen. Apart from that your `foo` is correct.

Comment: If you want to use foo for any kind of meaningful workflow control, you'll still need to handle its result in the caller again.

Comment: @o_weisman `NULL` on many systems have the value of 0 and surprisingly often the type of `int`.  So although an `int` can have the value of `NULL`, this is not what OP needs to code.

Comment: Your real problem is that you have no unison error checking system. Make it so that all your functions return an error code, for example an `enum`, and then check that one. I would suggest you solve this real problem, instead of creating some ugly, artificial patch.

Comment: @all Thanks for the feedback.  I think a union is what I need to resolve this issue.  I just didn't want to have multiple functions for multiple data type errors, and I didn't want to use a structure because of additional memory usage.

Comment: This entire idea is moot.  Using a union and checking for NULL first with an OR to check for an int seconds achieves a quantum state when the int is a zero there by causing the first check to report a null condition.  Reversing the order changes nothing.  So in the end it looks like a union in a struct with an indicator of what to test for is necessary.  Though I'm always looking for better ideas.  In software meritocracy wins.  @Lundin All my functions return a pass / fail condition.  The above code is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

AS per your code, if the pointer is not allocated it will crash when you try to deference it. so better to validate the pointer value before comparing the integer value.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

// pass a pointer
int foo(int *ptr) {

    // match for int by dereference or if ptr is null
    if (ptr == NULL) 
    {
        printf("match\n");
    } 
    else if(*ptr == -1 )
    {
       printf("match\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // make a an int
    int a = -1;

    // attempt to make int null?
    a = NULL;

    foo(&a);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Good point on the short circuiting, but this is not the solution I was after.  I apologize as my inquiry was not clearly phrased.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the order of condition like this:

// pass a pointer
int foo(int *ptr) {

```
// match for int by dereference or if ptr is null
if ((ptr == NULL) || (*ptr == -1)) {
    printf("match\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

incase of NULL pointer, the condition is matched and no need to dereference.

Comment: Good point on the short circuiting, but this is not the solution I was after.  I apologize as my inquiry was not clearly phrased.